# Sens d'une question avec une tournure negative

Tags: grammaire, sens, orthographe, questions

J'ai posé un jour la question « Qui n'est pas anti-GAFAM ? » sur un serveur discord. J'ai mis deux réponses disponibles, « Moi»" et « Pas moi ».

J'ai donc posé ma question avec une tournure négative pour inclure dans « moi » le groupe « pro-GAFAM » et le groupe « je m'en fiche des GAFAM » et dans « pas moi » inclure « anti-GAFAM ».

Ma logique est la suivante, si j'avais demandé « Qui est pour les GAFAM ? » avec comme réponses disponibles « Moi » et « Pas moi » je n'inclurais uniquement que les groupes « anti-GAFAM » et « pro-GAFAM » or si je pose la question avec une tournure négative, je trouve que cela sous-entend, que l'on peut être nuancé, donc « s'en fiche des GAFAM » (Un genre de neutre) comme je l'ai dit plus haut.

Il se trouve que certains membres du serveur ne sont pas d'accord avec cette logique, je souhaiterais donc connaitre votre avis sur la question et éventuellement que vous me donniez votre logique.
Cette question est bien évidemment ouverte !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a matter of pure logic and it has nothing to do with a particular question about French, even in that part of the French language that concerns this discipline.

Comment: Some confirmation of the exactitude of your deductions could be gained from a proof that is posted in the chat area « [Chez Cosette](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53028188#53028188) ».

Comment: @LPH Je suis d'accord, c'est une affaire de logique.

Comment: I find my initial point of view untenable. It is a fact that only pure logic  yields a result in the present case, but it is not a result in logic itself; it is a result on how logic as applied to the language according to a more or less established usage can ensure that from given forms in the language certain  deductions in the language become inescapable.  In all such cases of questions involving logic similarly, it appears now to me that it is preferable to keep to the point of view that a language feature is concerned, although it rests solely upon underlying logic principles.

Comment: Consequently, I retract my vote.

Comment: I am voting to leave this open because expressions of double (or even triple) negatives can have different meanings in different languages. That being said, a general question about the double negative with this example as clarification might be a better format for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Salut,

par logique qui n'est pas anti-GAFAM = anti-anti-GAFAM, soit deux négations, ce qui rend la phrase positive : qui est pro-GAFAM.

Donc répondre "Moi", revient à dire que tu supportes les GAFAM.
Et donc répondre "Pas moi" revient à dire que tu es anti-GAFAM.

Voilà, en espérant avoir pu t'aider.

Comment: Rooooooooh j'en était sur, tu pouvais pas t'en empêcher... Mais d'un autre côté t'as le droit puisque c'est une question ouvert

Comment: Il n'y a dans votre réponse que des principes vrais dans toutes les langues du monde, c'est à dire qui n'ont rien à voir avec la langue française ; ce sont des principes de logique ; le sujet que cette question introduit est celui de la logique pure ;  pour commencer, la question est hors sujet.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour monsieur Equette.

À mon avis, voici les groupes :

- moi => pas anti GAFAM = pro GAFAM / neutre
- pas moi => pas pas anti GAFAM = anti GAFAM

Donc tu as probablement raison

**EDIT :** Je ne peux pas commenter en dessous de 50 de réputation, ceci est donc une réponse à Guysmow

> qui n'est pas anti-GAFAM = anti-anti-GAFAM

C'est faux mais bon continuons

> ce qui rend la phrase positive : qui est pro-GAFAM

Là non. Anti anti GAFAM est quelqu'un qui est contre les anti GAFAM, donc sans interprétation on ne peut pas savoir si un anti anti GAFAM est pour ou contre les GAFAM

Comment: Il n'y a dans votre réponse que des principes vrais dans toutes les langues du monde, c'est à dire qui n'ont rien à voir avec la langue française ; ce sont des principes de logique ; le sujet que cette question introduit est celui de la logique pure ; pour commencer, la question est hors sujet.

Answer (score 1):

Les personnes censées répondre sont celles qui ne sont pas anti-GAFAM, la question doit être posée autrement.

> **Soutenez-vous les GAFAM ?**
>
> - Vous êtes anti-GAFAM.
> - Vous êtes pro-GAFAM.
> - Vous êtes partagé.
> - Vous n'avez pas d'avis.

Les questions qu'on trouve dans un questionnaire ne sont pas forcément évidentes, faciles à poser.

On pourrait poser la question différemment.

> Soutenez-vous les GAFAM ?
>
> - Oui.
> - Non.
> - Peu importe.

C'est sans doute une question de perspectives. On peut aussi interpréter « anti » comme une opposition ou une alternative.

> ### Dictionnaire Le Petit Robert
>
> ANT(I)– Élément, du grec *anti* « en face de, contre » [...]

Comment: Il n'est pas du tout demandé de trouver comment poser la question ni si l'une plutôt que l'autre des deux façons serait correcte ; il y a en vérité deux façons correctes énoncées et la question est de savoir si ce que l'on déduit à partir de ces deux façon serait conforme à la logique avancée par le demandeur de question. Il n'est pas question de la langue française, pas du tout ; ce n'est que de la logique pure, même si à un niveau très élémentaire.

Comment: Your editing of the question introduced such a distortion that it became something totally different ; you can't do that. I had to get back to the original phrasing (essentially).

Answer (score 0):

La déduction est juste sauf dans la dernière partie. Le raisonnement est entièrement parallèle dans la seconde partie, d'où le fait que l'on doit avoir « un neutre » aussi dans ce cas. La seule différence entre les deux possibilités est qu'alors que les neutres sont sous « moi »  dans la première option, ils sont sous « pas moi » dans la seconde. 
Pour simplifier la déduction il est nécessaire d'utiliser quelques symboles. Des stages intermédiaires soit évidents ou considérés come triviaux sont inclus, mais ils peuvent faciliter la compréhension du débutant dans ces questions de logique et de théorie des ensembles.

∈ : appartient

∉ : n'appartient pas

u : réunion d'ensembles

⏋ : négation, non

x : variable

P,Q : propriétés

r : individu

P(x) : x a la propriété P

⏋Q(x) : négation de « x a la propriété Q », donc « x n'a pas la propriété Q (même chose pour P,R,S,…)

A, B, N : des ensembles des « anti G », des « pour G » et des « neutres » respectivement

U : ensemble universel ; dans le présent problème l'ensemble universel est l'ensemble des personnes qui ont entendu parler de GAFAM mais pas seulement celles-là ; il comprend l'humanité entière si l'on veut ou bien tous les humains connectés à l'internet. Les conclusions d'un problème sont dépendantes de comment on choisit cet ensemble mais dans un problème de linguistique général on doit assumer que c'est l'ensemble le plus compréhensif. Si par exemple on décide de le limiter dans le premier cas (pas anti G) à l'union de l'ensemble de ceux qui sont pour (X), celui de ceux qui sont contre (Y) et celui de ceux qui sont neutre (N) (U = A u B u N) mais que dans le second cas (pour les G) on se limite à un ensemble universel qui exclu N (U = A u B), on manque de consistance ou plutôt on se place dans un autre système. Donc l'assomption implicite qui est faite dans le premier cas doit être maintenue et en vérité sans précision particulière dans l'énoncé d'où le problème est tiré on inclus non seulement les neutres mais ceux tous les autres qui ne sont pas informés du tout.

c(A) : complément de A, c'est à dire ce qui n'est pas dans A ; A étant inclus dans l'ensemble universel, c(A) consiste du reste de l'ensemble universel lorsque A en est enlevé.

⟺ : équivalent à ce qui précède (abus d'une notation standard mais qui facilite les choses)

{x/P(x)} : ensemble de tous les éléments x qui ont la propriété P; dit autrement : tous les x tels que P(x) *ou encore* l'ensemble des x tels que P(x)

=============================================================

P(x): x est anti G ; tous les x tel que P(x) : A ; A = {x/P(x)}

Demander « qui n'est pas anti-G » revient à demander qui n'appartient pas à A; qui n'appartient pas à A appartient au complément de A ; cet ensemble est c(A) ; c(A) = {x/x ∉ A}

Les réponses disponibles sont donc respectivement soit r ∈ c(A), soit ⏋(r ∈ c(A)) ;

r ∈ c(A); ⟺ r ∉ A;⟺ r ∉ {x/P(x)}; ⟺ ⏋P(r); ⟺ r n'est pas anti G

⏋(r ∈ c(A)); ⟺ r ∉ c(A); ⟺ r ∈ A;⟺ r ∈ {x/P(x)};⟺ P(r);⟺ r est anti G

(respectivement) r n'est pas anti G (pro ou neutre) ou r est anti G
(*« pro ou neutre » parce que r est dans le complément de A*)

===============================================================

Q(x): x est pro G ; tous les x tel que Q(x) : B; B={x/Q(x)}

Demander « qui est pro-G » revient à demander qui appartient à B; qui n'appartient pas à B appartient au complément de B ; cet ensemble est c(B) ; c(B) = {x/x ∉ B}

Les réponses disponibles sont donc soit r ∈ B, soit ⏋(r ∈ B) (respectivement);

r ∈ B; ⟺ r ∈ {x/Q(x)}; ⟺ Q(r); r est pro G

⏋(r ∈ B); ⟺ r ∉ B; ⟺ r ∈ c(B);⟺ r ∈ {x/⏋Q(x)};⟺ ⏋Q(r);⟺ r n'est pas pro G

(respectivement) r est pro G ou r n'est pas pro G (anti ou neutre)
(*« pro ou neutre » parce que r est dans le complément de B*)